# Converting string to float with atof() in C++

Tags: c++, math, atoi

I'm new to C++ and I need help converting my string variable into a number. I need to print the person's age and her next year age on the screen but I can't figure out how. I can't use the string to do math. So can you please shoot me a couple examples please?

I tried to do it this way:

```
  //converts F to C
  ctemp=(ftemp-32)*5.0/9.0;

  //calculates age
  age2 = age + 1 ; age2 = atof (age2.c_str()); age = atof (age.c_str());


  cout<<name<<" is "<<age<<" now, and will be " <<age2<<" a year from now.\n"<<"Its "<<ftemp<<" in "<<city<<"--- That's "<<setprecision(2)<<ctemp<<" degrees C"<<endl;
```

**Edit:**

```
int main() { 
    int city; 
    double ftemp, ctemp,age,age2;
    string buf,name; //Ask user to enter age, name, temperature and city 
    cout<<"Enter your age\n"; 
    cin>>buf; 
    age = atof(buf.c_str()); 
    cout<<"Enter your full name please\n"; 
    getline(cin,name); 
    cout<<"Enter the outside temperature please\n"; 
    cin>>buf; 
    ftemp=atof(buf.c_str()); 
    cout<<"Enter the current city you are in\n"; 
    cin>>buf; 
    city=atoi(buf.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Where do you get those values from?

Comment: Use `std::stof`. It has error checking and doesn't require a needless `c_str()` call.

Comment: Shall we *guess* how these variable are declared, an where their values come from ?

Comment: @chris It requires C++11, though...

Comment: why don't declare age and ages as float, and then do your math
and after all cout them or save it on a file.

Comment: What exactly has `ctemp` to do with your question? You should provide your coding attempt to solve the problem not just a selection of code snippets found somewhere! That said, you probably should use `float` or `atof()` but rather `int` and `atoi()` or, preferrably, `stoi()` if you can use C++11. Finally, the approach to deal with your problems is to convert the string into an `int` and then do the computation as there are no arithmetic computations on strings.

Comment: @olevegard, Which is two years old now, but there are still string streams and Boost, which both have error checking, and `strto*` for a C approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stringstreams to convert the string to the data type you want:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::string num_str = "10.5";

  std::istringstream iss(num_str);

  float f_val = 0;

  iss >> f_val;

  //this will output 10.5 (as expected)
  std::cout << f_val << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Which will assign `f_val` to the value of the string.

This approach is preferred in that it has built-in checking of conversion, and it can work on any of the fundamental C++ types. Hence, if you can can create a template function to perform the checking for you and return that particular value of the type you desire:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
T ConvertStringToNumber(const std::string& str)  
{  
  std::istringstream ss(str);  
  T number = 0;  

  ss >> number;  

  if (ss.fail( )) 
  {
    throw std::invalid_argument("ConvertStringToNumber:" + str);
  }

   return number;  
}

int main(int argc, char argv[]){
  std::string num_str = "10.5";
  float f = ConvertStringToNumber<float>(num_str);

  std::cout << f << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the Fahrenheit to Centigrade (Celsius) conversion isn't mentioned, we'll ignore it.

As originally written, the question seems to be asking about the line:

```
age2 = age + 1 ; age2 = atof (age2.c_str()); age = atof (age.c_str());
```

We are not shown the declarations.  For the time being, I'll assume there's a prior declaration:

```
double age, age2;
```

Given that (and assuming no other manipulation of `age` or `age2` before this line), setting `age2` to `age + 1` adds one to an undefined value and stores it in `age2`.  Then the stored value is assigned the result of converting ... hold on, you're joking ... the result of converting `age2` to a C string and applying `atof()` to the result.  So, maybe my assumed type for `age2` is wrong — it is really `std::string`?  But if `age2` is a string, you've got problems with the prior assignment, and this `age2 = atof(age2.c_str());` assignment doesn't work either.  Similar issues apply to the `age = atof(age.c_str());` assignment.  The logic should be 'assign to `age`; `age2 = age + 1;`'.

```
str:string s_age = "21";
double age = atof(s_age.c_str());
double age2 = age + 1;

std::cout << "Age: " << age << ", Next year: " << age2 << endl;
```

Think about sequencing.  Think about types.  When you next ask a question, show the types!  Look up what it takes to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) and make the code in your question an SSCCE if at all possible.

I'm ducking the discussion of whether `atof()` (or `atoi()` as originally mentioned in the question title but not mentioned again in the body of the question) is a good way to convert a C string into a `double` or `int`; there are better ways to do those conversions in both C and C++, and the mechanisms in C++ are different from those in C, especially when the source string is a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

1. as I said in a comment above, use **float** for age and ages:

   ```
   float age, age2;
   // do math
   cout<<name<<" is "<<age<<" now, and will be " <<age2<<" a year from now.\n";
   ```
2. use Qt as your C++ Framework and enjoy C++

   ```
   QString age("15.5");
   double temp = age.toDouble();
   ```

Comment: @OruzAysn: `atoi` is ok for an introductory assignment, but it does no error checking; for example, `atoi("This is not a number")` either yields `0` or has undefined behavior, I don't remember which.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thats correct but unfortunately we are still at the very beginning of learning C++.. He wants us to use the way he says. Im just confused and dissapointed to not to be able to write that simple code.. Anyway.. Just cant figure out why i can print out the age..

Comment: @int main()
{
  int city;
  double ftemp, ctemp,age,age2;
  string buf,name;
  
  //Ask user to enter age, name, temperature and city
  cout<<"Enter your age\n";
  cin>>buf; age = atof (buf.c_str());
  cout<<"Enter your full name please\n";
  getline(cin,name);
  
  cout<<"Enter the outside temperature please\n";
  cin>>buf; ftemp=atof(buf.c_str());
  cout<<"Enter the current city you are in\n";
  cin>>buf; city=atoi(buf.c_str());

Comment: I Edit your post by adding your last comment @Oruz Aysn

Answer (score -2):

```
#include "iostream.h"

main() {
    float a,b,rmvivek,arni;
    char ch="123.00"; 
    a=atof(ch);
    arni=a+2*5;
    cout  << "the a value is" << arni;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if your could add some explanation to your code.

Comment: It would also be great if this were valid C++.